# Cannot publish anymore since Asp.net5 RC1 Update

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, publish

I upgraded my project to the new RC1 a couple of days ago and it went without any problems (at first). The code runs and I can test it on my local IIS but when I try to publish it to my Azure web app nothing happens. No error or anything else. I press publish in the preview view and it disappears but that’s it. I tried already to make a new project that started at Rc1 because I thought that there is hidden somewhere a Beta8 reference I could not find but that did nothing.

Would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. It did not have anything to do with the new RC1 release. I must accidently put the Properties folder in my solution explorer on “hide in solution explorer”. If this is the case VS will not publish, and that without any errors.

Sorry if someone wasted time on this 